# Solver (cbc) returned non-zero return code (3)

Tags: pyomo, coin-or-cbc

I am using pyomo and CBC solver to solve a series of binary inetger linear programming problems and it works most of the time but I have come across this error

```
Cbc0010I After 17900 nodes, 8056 on tree, -3.6158666e+008 best solution, 
best possible -3.6158709e+008 (2312.55 seconds)
ERROR: "[base]\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", 600, solve
    Solver (cbc) returned non-zero return code (3)
ERROR: "[base]\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", 603, solve
    See the solver log above for diagnostic information.
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-3-14e70af11ac8>", line 26, in <module>
results = opt.solve(instance, tee=True)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", 
line 607, in solve
"Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)

ApplicationError: Solver (cbc) did not exit normally
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Try running with tee=True option and see what happens.

Comment: There's no additional output that you're receiving from `tee=True`? Are you using CBC through the AMPL interface? If so, try the `halt_on_ampl_error` `yes` option.

Comment: I am using CBC though pyomo. There are lots of other outputs but nothing on the error, other than what comes after the above...which I have just updated to include more...

Comment: Try running with the `keepfiles=True` solve option so that the full CBC log file is kept?

Comment: Thanks. If I do that the first few lines of output read: `Solver log file: 'C:\Users\dwelch\AppData\Local\Temp\5\tmpe3pfujn2.cbc.log'` but I cant find this log file anywhere? Any thoughts on this?

Comment: D. Welch, did you find a solution to this error?  I'm experiencing the same thing...

Comment: No I dont think so. It seems to be hard to figure out whats going on when this happens. Sorry